# Why Linux-based-laptop has slower wifi connection that windows-based-laptop?

Tags: wireless, laptop, atheros

I had ever tried many distros: ubuntu, debian, xubuntu, freya, fedora, etc. And they all have slower wifi than when I was using windows.

Is there any explanation about this? How to find appropriate wifi-driver for my os linux?

update:
I have add this comand on terminal
`lpsci -knn | grep Net -A2`

the output is:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company AR9485/HB125 802.11bgn 1×1 Wi-Fi Adapter [103c:1838]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I have updated it :)

Comment: How do you measure speed?

Comment: sometimes I use speedtest.net

Comment: but I feel more slow when using browser on linux and my wifi often disconnected, this never happen when I use windows (the same laptop)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1746326) in the Ubuntu forums, the following command, followed by a reboot, will greatly improve your WiFi speed using the ath9k driver:

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Comment: @muslimwww: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: From https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath9k/bugs, under "Common misconceptions": Do not use the module parameter “nohwcrypt” unless you know that the HW/chip is buggy regarding frame encryption/decryption.